# Excluding path in url using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My angular application has multiple pages which users can visit and I would like to hide all other urls and only show users the base url. So imagine my base url is: www.example.com and I have other pages like About, Contact Us etc. Currently, when the user clicks on About, the url changes to www.example.com/about. Is it possible for angular not to add the "/about"? Is this possible using angular js? Also, I have been searching for solutions and have experimented with ui-router.js, is it also possible with this module?

Comment: You could just show/hide parts of your page when the user clicks, e.g. using `ng-hide` and `ng-show`. Then again, I am wondering why the user shouldn't know where he/she actually is on your page. Plus, the user won't be able to bookmark and visit the specific site (e.g. "About") later without doing some extra clicks.

Comment: I used about and contact as examples. I don't want the user to be able to bookmark the link when they navigate hence why I want to remove it from the url.

Comment: Yes this is possible using `$routeProvider`. You can define what url goes to what page. So for example `/about` goes to `about.html` or even `randomPage.html`, but it still shows `/about` in the url.

Comment: @simpe, I don't want it to show /about in the url. I already have the $routeProvider set up for all pages.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I'm not sure how you'd do what you're asking with separate pages. Perhaps if you were include them using `ng-include` or something like that, then the url would stay the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using ui-router, then you can define states without specifying urls like

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('state1', {
            url: "/state1",
            templateUrl: "state1.html",
            controller: 'Controller3'
        })
        .state('state2', {
            templateUrl: "state2.html",
            controller: 'Controller2'
        })
        .state('state3', {
            templateUrl: "state3.html",
            controller: 'Controller3'
        })
});
```

So by default the url will be /state1. And you can implement navigation by using ui-sref directive in your template like `ui-sref="state2"` or using $state service in your controller like `$state.go('state2')`.

Comment: Only problem is that ui-router won't call `window.history.pushState(...` when the state doesn't have url. So the back button on the navigator or the back button on android won't work as expected.