# Angular.js - Route without changing URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

In Angular.js, can we route to a different page without changing URL in the address bar? 
I want to update the view without changing the URL as if the user has moved to a new web page.

Comment: Basically, change the template used inside the current `ng-view` without having the URL in the address bar changed. Like how the `ng-include` works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excluding path in url using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758229/excluding-path-in-url-using-angularjs)